# Python SQlite. LIMIT variable does not change value in a loop

Tags: python, sqlite, loops, for-loop, select

I am trying to find the difference in the number SEN students in each row. (code, output and database table is at the bottom)

What I have done:

```
Finding the number of rows in a table.

Initializing the LIMIT number to 0 BEFORE the loop starts.

I then add one to LIMIT and output it as a string.

I then select the number of SEN students at LIMIT currLimitStr 

I then add one to LIMIT and output it as a string.

I then select the number of SEN students at LIMIT currLimitStr 

I then fetch this data and print it out.

The loop starts again.
```

Incrementing `currLimit` 2 every loop works BUT for some reason the same values of senRow1 and senRow2 are being used after every loop. Why is this the case

```
countNumRows = cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM SEN_Table")
countNumFetch = countNumRows.fetchone()
countNumRowsTable = countNumFetch[0]
print("Number of rows in the table: " +  str(countNumRowsTable))
currLimit = 0
for x in range(0, countNumRowsTable):
    currLimit = currLimit + 1
    currLimit1Str = str(currLimit)
    senRow1 = cur.execute("SELECT SenNumber FROM SEN_Table ORDER BY SenNumber DESC limit " + currLimit1Str)
    currLimit = currLimit + 1
    currLimit2Str = str(currLimit)
    senRow2 = cur.execute("SELECT SenNumber FROM SEN_Table ORDER BY SenNumber DESC limit " + currLimit2Str)

    senRow1Num = senRow1.fetchone()[0]
    senRow2Num = senRow2.fetchone()[0]
    print(senRow1Num)
    print(senRow2Num)
    print("")
    senDiff = print(senRow1Num - senRow2Num)
    print("")
```

The output:

[image]

The database table:

[image]

Comment: Because you are always looking at the same field in the same record.

Comment: but i am incrementing the limit

Comment: So what? It is still the same field in the same record.

Comment: the limit changes which rows are returned

Comment: But you are looking at the first row which is always the same.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: have you even researched what the limit does

Comment: Have you even printed the whole recordset returned by each query to see what's going on?

Comment: yes. the numbers are the only items in the list returned

Comment: Maybe add a key to the list of fields so you can identify each record.

Comment: how would that help me

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do something like this? Have you even read on how to use [`LIMIT` and `OFFSET`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset)?

Comment: @zwer who are you refering to

Comment: i want to go through a table or values and minus the difference between them to find out if there are any forms that have a larger number than 2 students than another form. But the user inputs the number of forms they want so the number of rows in the table is not fixed hence the reason why i am using a loop

Comment: @AdamAzamYear12 It would show you that you are always looking at the same record.

Comment: @zwer i want to go through a table or values and minus the difference between them to find out if there are any forms that have a larger number than 2 students than another form. But the user inputs the number of forms they want so the number of rows in the table is not fixed hence the reason why i am using a loop

Comment: @Goyo how about I show you a different example. I will update my question

Comment: @Goyo this time the SEN numbers are different and the output corresponds to this difference.

Comment: I've been experimenting for a few hours but still can't figure out why. @zwer do you have any thoughts on why it is not working properly.

Comment: have you given up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not really understand what you want so I cannot help you to achieve it. Hopefully I can help you to understand why your code does what it does.

I added some lines to your code and annotated them with numbers `#n` in order to reference them in my explanations. The output of my code is prefixed with an asterisk so you can tell it apart and does not interfere with yours.

### Cursor.execute() returns a reference to the same cursor.

Hence `senRow1` and `senRow2` are actually **the same object** as proven by `#5` where this identity is asserted. And when you fetch the first row of `senRow1` and the first row of `senrow2` you are actually fecthing the two first rows of the same cursor, call it `cur`, `senRow1` or `senRow2`, they are all different names for the same thing.

Actually executing the first query is useless because before doing anything with it you execute the second one in the very same cursor and the result of the first one is lost.

### Changing the limit changes the number of rows but does not change the first rows.

In order to demonstrate it I create two cursors in `#1` and `#2`, execute the queries in `#3` and `#4` and print all the rows in `#6` and `#7`. As you can see the number of rows returned varies with the limit, but **the first rows remain the same** regardless the limit.

Note that I am printing the result of the first query for the shake of completeness, but as explained before only the second one is relevant to your code.

Thus in each iteration of the loop you are looking at the first two rows returned by the second query. And those two rows are the same in each iteration.

The modified code:

```
countNumRows = cur.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM SEN_Table")
countNumFetch = countNumRows.fetchone()
countNumRowsTable = countNumFetch[0]
print("Number of rows in the table: " +  str(countNumRowsTable))
currLimit = 0

cursor1 = conn.cursor()  #1
cursor2 = conn.cursor()  #2

for x in range(0, countNumRowsTable):
    currLimit = currLimit + 1
    currLimit1Str = str(currLimit)
    senRow1 = cur.execute("SELECT SenNumber FROM SEN_Table ORDER BY SenNumber DESC limit " + currLimit1Str)
    cursor1.execute("SELECT SenNumber FROM SEN_Table ORDER BY SenNumber "
                    "DESC limit " + currLimit1Str)  #3

    currLimit = currLimit + 1
    currLimit2Str = str(currLimit)
    senRow2 = cur.execute("SELECT SenNumber FROM SEN_Table ORDER BY SenNumber DESC limit " + currLimit2Str)
    cursor2.execute("SELECT SenNumber FROM SEN_Table ORDER BY SenNumber "
                    "DESC limit " + currLimit2Str)  #4

    assert(senRow1 is senRow2)  #5
    print('* cursor1: {}'.format(cursor1.fetchall()))  #6
    print('* cursor2: {}'.format(cursor2.fetchall()))  #7

    senRow1Num = senRow1.fetchone()[0]  # the 1st row of cur, senRow1
                                        # or senRow2 (they are the same)
    senRow2Num = senRow2.fetchone()[0]  # the 2nd row of cur, senRow1 or
                                        # senRow2 (they are the same)
    print(senRow1Num)
    print(senRow2Num)
    print("")
    senDiff = print(senRow1Num - senRow2Num)
    print("")
```

The output:

```
Number of rows in the table: 5
* cursor1: [(4,)]
* cursor2: [(4,), (3,)]
4
3

1

* cursor1: [(4,), (3,), (3,)]
* cursor2: [(4,), (3,), (3,), (2,)]
4
3

1

* cursor1: [(4,), (3,), (3,), (2,), (1,)]
* cursor2: [(4,), (3,), (3,), (2,), (1,)]
4
3

1

* cursor1: [(4,), (3,), (3,), (2,), (1,)]
* cursor2: [(4,), (3,), (3,), (2,), (1,)]
4
3

1

* cursor1: [(4,), (3,), (3,), (2,), (1,)]
* cursor2: [(4,), (3,), (3,), (2,), (1,)]
4
3

1
```

Comment: THANKS FOR THE EXPLANATION. I have changed my design to the problem by using loop to iterate through the rows and add their values to a list and then find the differences. That way the solution is a lot  more organised